# Expire cookie on browser close or x mins

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

I know that not putting an expires part in will create a session cookie. So the cookie gets deleted on browser close.

But I want to create a cookie that gets deleted either on browser close or x mins. (which ever occurs first say 10 mins).

So when I set the cookie, and stay logged in to application for more than 10 mins, even though I have not closed my browser, cookie must be deleted. 
How to do that?

Comment: What's the problem with setting a cookie with expiry of 10 minutes? The cookie won't be deleted if you close the browser after 5 minutes, and then you reopen. But that's probably what the user expects. When you come back to SO tomorrow, you'll be logged in. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Gavriel No I wanted the user to logout if he closes the browser or should not be able to do any activity if he is logged in for more than 10 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to write setTimeOut function to unset the cookie.

for example you have set a cookie like :

```
document.cookie="somekey=something; expires=; path=yourdomain.com";
```

you just need to write a javascript code some where in a js file to unset on certain time out.(here 3sec)

```
setTimeout(function(){document.cookie="somekey=; expires=; path=yourdomain.com"},3000)
```

or to delete all cookie

```
setTimeout(function(){document.cookie=""},3000)
```